# stopping an io_service object and boost::asio::io_service::work

Tags: c++, boost

```
boost::asio::io_service m_io_service;
boost::asio::io_service::work m_work(m_io_service);
m_io_service.run()
m_io_service.stop(); 
m_io_service.reset();
m_io_service.run(); //work object still used here or should I recreate a m_work object?
```

If I stop a io_service object, then start it again, do I need to rebind it to a work object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way is to have

```
optional<asio::io_service::work> m_work(asio::io_service::work(m_io_service));
```

or

```
shared_ptr<asio::io_service::work> m_work = make_shared<asio::io_service::work>(m_io_service);
```

So you can, in both cases, signal "shutdown for the service using

```
m_work.reset();
```

And, no I don't think you need to rebind a work object. Work objects are not actual async operations. It's more like a refcount/lock